# Create an alias for multiple items in a csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

I have several items that should be removed from Content, Compile, and EmbeddedResource.
I do this like this now:

```xml
    <Content Remove="data\**" />
    <Content Remove="other\**" />
    <Content Remove="etc\**" />

    <Compile Remove="data\**" />
    <Compile Remove="other\**" />
    <Compile Remove="etc\**" />

    <EmbeddedResource Remove="data\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="other\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="etc\**" />
```

This works, but bloats the project file significantly. Ideally, I'd like to create something like:

```xml
    <RemoveAll Include="data\**" />

   ... some magic that checks RemoveAll and 
       emits Content, Compile and EmbeddedResource for all RemoveAlls 
   ...
```

Is this possible in csproj? I've already experimented a bit with targets, but I couldn't get a target to remove these items.

Comment: As an alternative, could you put all those resources in a subfolder, and then exclude that subfolder?

Comment: @MatthewWatson No, unfortunately I have no control over it, it's created by a third party dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The only approach I'm aware of would be:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <RemoveMe Include="data\**" />
   <RemoveMe Include="other\**" />
   <RemoveMe Include="etc\**" />

   <None Remove="@(RemoveMe)" />
   <Compile Remove="@(RemoveMe)" />
   <EmbeddedResource Remove="@(RemoveMe)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

> I've already experimented a bit with targets, but I couldn't get a target to remove these items.

Note that removing items in targets will not remove them from Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. The view of the project in SE comes from evaluation, where no targets are executed.

Comment: Hmm, that freezes VS for me.